# HTML within PHP with php variables codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

in my controller I am generating datatables with ajax here is code:

```
....
$this->loadViews("customers/customer_view", $this->global,  $data);
        $this->load->view ( '/includes/footer' );
    }
        public function ajax_list()
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $list = $this->customer->get_datatables();
            $data = array();
            $no = $_POST['start'];
            foreach ($list as $customer) {
                $no++;
                $row = array();
                $row[] = '<input type="checkbox" class="data-check" value="'.$customer->customerID.'">';
                $row[] = $customer->custcode;
                $row[] = $customer->Name;
                $row[] = $customer->Address;
                $row[] = $customer->CellNo;
                $row[] = $customer->BottlesQty;
                $row[] = $customer->Rate;
                $row[] = $customer->DeliveryDay;
                $row[] = $customer->'<div class=" form-check checkbox-slider-md checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-warning"><label><input type="checkbox" name="status" class="status" onclick="toggle(\'.status\', this)" value="0" ''if ( $customer->status == \'\') { echo "checked disabled"; } .''   ><span><div id="statusactive" style="visibility: show; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span> <span><div id="statusinactive" style="visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span></label></div>';

                //add html for action
                $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary form-check checkbox-slider-md" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$customer->customerID."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$customer->customerID."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

                $data[] = $row;
            }

            $output = array(
                            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                            "recordsTotal" => $this->customer->count_all(),
                            "recordsFiltered" => $this->customer->count_filtered(),
                            "data" => $data,
                    );
            //output to json format
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
```

Datatables generated successfully but when I am trying to format a check box in tablt it is giving following error

```
Message: syntax error, unexpected ''<div class=" form-check check' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

The code where is error is as follows:

```
$row[] = $customer->'<div class=" form-check checkbox-slider-md checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-warning"><label><input type="checkbox" name="status" class="status" onclick="toggle(\'.status\', this)" value="0" ''if ( $customer->status == \'\') { echo "checked disabled"; } .''   ><span><div id="statusactive" style="visibility: show; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span> <span><div id="statusinactive" style="visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span></label></div>';
```

Please help me to resolve issue.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that line to do? `$customer` is an object and the `->` is an object property accessor.

Comment: actually this line will show with a slider that customer Active OR NOT and when clicked call toggle jquery script

Comment: What's odd is that you're doing it correctly on the very next line

Comment: yes I know but I can't figure it out in this line

Comment: Are you editing code that you didn't write? I honestly don't see how you could write the `//add html for action` line and not figure out this one.

Comment: ha ha this app I have to deliver and they requested to comment briefly for any future change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object->property` means that you take **property** of **object**. I doubt that your `$customer` object has property with html-code of div. So, remove `$customer`:

```
$row[] = '<div class=" form-check checkbox-slider-md checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-warning"><label><input type="checkbox" name="status" class="status" onclick="toggle(\'.status\', this)" value="0" ''if ( $customer->status == \'\') { echo "checked disabled"; } .''   ><span><div id="statusactive" style="visibility: show; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span> <span><div id="statusinactive" style="visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div></span></label></div>';
```

Additional fix is replacing `if` inside this bunch of html to ternary operator:

```
$row[] = '<div class=" form-check checkbox-slider-md checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-warning">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="status" class="status" onclick="toggle(\'.status\', this)" value="0" '
     . ( $customer->status == '' ?  "checked disabled" : '' ) . '>
         <span>
             <div id="statusactive" style="visibility: show; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div>
         </span> 
         <span>
             <div id="statusinactive" style="visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 45px;"> Inactive</div>
         </span>
    </label>
</div>';
```

Comment: no dear customer->status is getting value from db and checking either it is true or false

Comment: See the update with `customer->status`. And read __again__ first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Same error dear

Comment: Second snippet has __no errors__. If you have - then you're doing something wrong.